# Displaying result from ML model

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, postman

I'm creating an API that functions to load wav files and process them with ML models that have been deployed on cloud run. when I tried to test it on postman, I hoped to get the predicted results but apparently they couldn't appear. I have tested this model using python and it runs smoothly, but not on node.js

result.js

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const filePath = "./audio_history/ch-4.wav"; // Specify the path to your WAV file

    // Read the audio file
    const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    // Make a POST request to the ML model API endpoint
    const mlModelEndpoint = "https://getprediction-7rpnuc6dkq-as.a.run.app";
    const response = await axios.post(mlModelEndpoint, { audio: fileData });

    // Extract the prediction result from the response
    const predictionResult = response.data.prediction;

    // Send the prediction result as the API response
    res.json({ prediction: predictionResult });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

output

```
{}
```

[image: postman]